# How to tell NPM install was successful

Tags: npm

How can I make sure this package is completely successfully installed?

Whenever I install a package in NPM I see no error, no successful message.

Maybe I'm little hypochondriac :)

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When your npm module has been installed successfully your last line should show installed module name and version: `<name>@<version>`, installed directory and the installed module dependencies.

In your case `mongojs` has been installed successfully and you can see output as follows:

```
...
mongojs@0.10.0 node_modules/mongojs
├── thunky@0.1.0
├── readable-stream@1.1.10 (debuglog@0.0.2, core-util-is@1.0.1)
└── mongodb@1.3.19 (kerberos@0.0.3, bson@0.2.2)
```

In case of installation errors you should see some error messages. Also the same information should be stored in `npm-debug.log` file, created in the current directory.

If I install `npm install mongojs@0.10.1` (that version of `mongojs` does not exits yet so I will not be able to install it successfully) I will get some errors:

[image: npm errors]

I hope that will help.

Comment: wouldn't be nice if they provide a "success" message :)

Comment: Been yrs but still no "success" message :D

Comment: Hi, if I am using `npm install` then how can tell all packages are installed successfully.